# How to Disable two buttons when only one is clicked in javascript without the use of Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have two buttons. I want when one button is clicked both of the buttons get disabled. I want to use only javascript without Jquery.

```js
var button1=document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener('click',function(){


//I want to check if either of the buttons were clicked and disable both of them.//

if(button1||button2===true){
button1.disable=true;
button2.disable=true;
Alert("Button Disable property is in a true state.");
}

});

var button2=document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener('click',function(){

//I want to check if either of the buttons were clicked and disable both of them.//

if(button1||button2===true){
button1.disable=true;
button2.disable=true;
Alert("Button Disable property is in a true state.");
}
});
//I also tried to set the {once : true;} at the end of the event handler but it only works for one button.Which means that I have to press both of them tfor them both to disable.//
```

```html
<button id="button1">Button1</button>
<button id="button2">button2</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of problems. Firstly, your variables are being set to the return value of `addEventListener`, not the document element. Secondly, to disable an element, you use `element.disabled = true`, not `element.disable = true`. Finally `alert` is all lowercase, not `Alert`. There are also optimisations that can be made to your code - for example there is no need to check if button1 or 2 was clicked since if the event listener is called then one of them must have been. Try this instead:

```js
var button1=document.getElementById("button1");
var button2=document.getElementById("button2");

[button1,button2].map(b => b.addEventListener('click',function(){
    button1.disabled=true;
    button2.disabled=true;
    alert("Button Disable property is in a true state.");
}));
```

```html
<button id="button1">Button1</button>
<button id="button2">button2</button>
```